# Trying to make a program that simulates typing

Tags: python

I'm trying to making a program where each keypress prints the next character in a predetermined string, so it's like the user is typing text.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
def typing(x):
  letter = 0
  for i in range(0, len(x)):
    getch.getch()
    print(x[letter], end = "")
    letter += 1
    
typing("String")
```

What happens here is you need to press 6 keys (The length of the string) and then it prints all at once. I can sort of fix this by removing the `, end = ""`, which makes the letters appear one at a time, but then the outcome looks like this:

```
S
t
r
i
n
g
```

Any ideas for making the letters appear one at a time and stay on the same line?

Comment: try running it as `python -u my_script.py` ... (with the `end=""`)

Comment: Try a sleep time, where the program waits a specified time before outputting the next character, which would give it the typing simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code which works for me:

```py
import time

def typewrite(word: str):
    for i in word:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(i, end="", flush = True)

typewrite("Hello World")
```

Comment: right on.  typo though: `welcome` = `word` and I'd add a newline `type( 'Hello World\n' )`

Comment: It's also bad practice to overwrite keywords `print( type(None) )`.  I'd call it `typed` or `typewrite` instead.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to edit, you can check it now. Thanks for the remark!